# How to parse value `@attribute` from a SimpleXMLObject in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am trying to parse the `starkoverflow.com/feeds/tag/{$tagName}`.
This is my code:

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/php");
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $attr = $simpleXml->entry->category->@attributes;

?>
```

When I execute the above code it gives me a error, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in D:\wamp\www\success\protoT.php on line 4`

So, My question is how to get the array of the `@attributes`?
[Scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npkxb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [appropriately documented method: attributes()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

```
$attr = $simpleXml->entry->category->attributes();
```

Except that `$simpleXml->entry->category` is an array, so you need to specify which entry in the array you want to access:

```
$attr = $simpleXml->entry->category[0]->attributes();
```

**EDIT**

Unless, as I have just learned, you only need to reference the first element

Comment: Voting down because the second half is incorrect: SimpleXML will happily assume that `->category` is equivalent to `->category[0]`

Comment: Something new for me to learn, never knew that.... though OP may need to use the array index to pick attributes from the other elements, so showing the syntax is still valid for that

Comment: Yep, this is what makes SimpleXML simple - it's *not* an array, it's an object with a lot of DWIM magic. :)

Answer (score 2):

The key is, to realise there is no <s>spoon</s> array.

To get all the attributes as an array, you can use the `attributes()` method:

```
$all_attributes = $simpleXml->entry->category->attributes();
```

However, most of the time, what you really want is a particular attribute, in which case you just use array key notation:

```
$id_attribute = $simpleXml->entry->category['id'];
```

Note that this returns an object; when passing it around, you generally want to have just the string representing its value:

```
$id_value = (string)$simpleXml->entry->category['id'];
```

The above will assume you always want the *first* `<category>` element in the *first* `<entry>`, even if there are multiple. It is actually short-hand for specifying the 0th item (which works even if there is only one of each element):

```
$id_value = (string)$simpleXml->entry[0]->category[0]['id'];
```

Or, of course, looping over each set (again, it doesn't matter if there are one or multiple, the `foreach` will still work):

```
foreach ( $simpleXml->entry as $entry ) {
    foreach ( $entry->category as $category ) {
        $id_value_for_this_category = (string)$category['id'];
    }
}
```