# Getting Value from Object with Characters in Element Name

Tags: php, object

I have an object being passed into a function which I have no control over and it is in the below format, with the root being 'entity'.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(17) "Test Object Value" } }
```

Now I'm trying to pull out just the name by using both the below snippets but both output empty values.

```
entity[0]->name;
```

and

```
entity->{'@attributes'}->name;
```

Is there a special way to deal with characters in element names when the curly brackets format doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `name` attribute as follows:

```
$name = $entity->attributes()->name;
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `attribute()` function for getting the attributes in a simpleXML object. Your code should be something like:

```
$parsed = $simplexmlObject->entity->attribute()->desiredProperty;
```

Update:  Got this technique from a question asked from me, [How to parse value `@attribute` from a SimpleXMLObject in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666196/how-to-parse-value-attribute-from-a-simplexmlobject-in-php)